# Theorem 6.12 (a) in Baby Rudin: $\int_a^b \left( f_1 + f_2 \right) d \alpha=\int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Here is part (a) of Theorem 6.12 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> If $f_1 \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ and $f_2 \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$, then 
>   $$f_1 + f_2 \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha), $$
>   and 
>   $$ \int_a^b \left( f_1 + f_2 \right) d \alpha = \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha,$$

And, here is Rudin's proof.

> If $f = f_1 + f_2$ and $P$ is any partition of $[a, b]$, we have 
>   $$ \tag{20} L\left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) + L\left(P, f_2, \alpha \right) \leq L\left(P, f, \alpha \right) \leq U\left(P, f, \alpha \right) \leq U\left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) + U\left(P, f_2, \alpha \right).$$
>   If $f_1 \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ and $f_2 \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$, let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. There are partitions $P_j$ $(j = 1, 2)$ such that 
>   $$ U \left( P_j, f_j, \alpha \right) -  L \left( P_j, f_j, \alpha \right) < \varepsilon. $$
>   These inequalities persist if $P_1$ and $P_2$ are replaced by their common refinement $P$. Then (20) implies 
>   $$ U (P, f, \alpha) - L (P, f, \alpha) < 2 \varepsilon, $$
>   which proves that $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.
>
> With this same $P$ we have 
>   $$ U \left( P, f_j , \alpha \right) < \int f_j d \alpha + \varepsilon \qquad (j = 1, 2); $$ 
>   hence (20) implies 
>   $$ \int f d \alpha \leq U ( P, f, \alpha) < \int f_1 d \alpha + \int f_2 d \alpha + 2 \varepsilon. $$
>   Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude that 
>   $$ \tag{21}  \int f d \alpha \leq \int f_1 d \alpha + \int f_2 d \alpha. $$
>   If we replace $f_1$ and $f_2$ in (21) by $- f_1$ and $- f_2$, the inequality is reversed, and the equality is proved.

Now here is my reading of Rudin's proof.

> Let $f = f_1 + f_2$, and let $P = \left\{ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \right\}$, where $$a = x_0 \leq x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_{n-1} \leq x_n = b,$$
>   be any partition of $[a, b]$.
>
> For each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, if $m_{1i}$, $m_{2i}$, and $m_i$ are the infima of $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f$, respectively, on $\left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, then we see that 
>   $$ m_{1i} \leq f_1(x), \qquad m_{2i} \leq f_2(x) \qquad (x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i ),$$
>   and so 
>   $$ m_{1i} + m_{2i} \leq f_1(x) + f_2(x) = f(x) \qquad (x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i ),$$
>   which in turn implies that 
>   $$ m_{1i} + m_{2i} \leq m_i \qquad ( i = 1, \ldots, n  ),$$
>   and as $\alpha$ is a monotonically increasing function on $[a, b]$, so
>   $$  m_{1i} \Delta \alpha_i + m_{2i}  \Delta \alpha_i \leq m_i  \Delta \alpha_i \qquad ( i = 1, \ldots, n  ),$$
>   where $ \Delta \alpha_i = \alpha\left( x_i \right) - \alpha\left( x_{i-1} \right)$. Adding all the inequalities for $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we thus obtain
>   $$ L\left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) +  L\left( P, f_2, \alpha \right) \leq L ( P, f, \alpha). \tag{20(1)} $$
>
> Similarly, for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, if $M_{1i}$, $M_{2i}$, and $M_i$ are the suprema of $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f$, respectively, on $\left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$, then we see that 
>   $$ M_{1i} \geq f_1(x), \qquad M_{2i} \geq f_2(x) \qquad (x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i ),$$
>   and so 
>   $$ M_{1i} + M_{2i} \geq f_1(x) + f_2(x) = f(x) \qquad (x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i ),$$
>   which in turn implies that 
>   $$ M_{1i} + M_{2i} \geq M_i \qquad ( i = 1, \ldots, n  ),$$
>   and as $\alpha$ is a monotonically increasing function on $[a, b]$, so
>   $$  M_{1i} \Delta \alpha_i + M_{2i}  \Delta \alpha_i \geq M_i  \Delta \alpha_i \qquad ( i = 1, \ldots, n  ),$$
>   and, adding together all these inequalities for $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we thus obtain
>   $$ U\left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) +  U\left( P, f_2, \alpha \right) \geq U ( P, f, \alpha). \tag{20(2)} $$
>   From (20(1)) and (20(2)) we obtain (20) in Rudin's proof.
>
> Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. As $f_1$ and $f_2$ are Riemann-integrable with respect to $\alpha$ over $[a, b]$, so (by Theorem 6.6 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition) we can find partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ of $[a, b]$ such that 
>   $$ U \left( P_1, f_1, \alpha \right) - L \left( P_1, f_1, \alpha \right) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \qquad  U \left( P_2, f_2, \alpha \right) - L \left( P_2, f_2, \alpha \right) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{1} $$
>   Now let $P = P_1 \cup P_2$. Then $P \supset P_1$ and $P \supset P_2$. Then (by Theorem 6.4 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition) we have 
>   $$ L \left( P_1, f_1, \alpha \right) \leq L (P, f_1, \alpha) \leq U(P, f_1, \alpha) \leq U(P_1, f_1, \alpha), $$ 
>   and 
>   $$  L \left( P_2, f_2, \alpha \right) \leq L (P, f_2, \alpha) \leq U(P, f_2, \alpha) \leq U(P_2, f_2, \alpha), $$
>   and so we can conclude that 
>   $$ U \left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) - L \left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) \leq U ( P_1, f_1, \alpha) - L(P_1, f_1, \alpha) < { \varepsilon \over 2 }, $$ 
>   and 
>   $$  U \left(P, f_2, \alpha \right) - L \left(P, f_2, \alpha \right) \leq U ( P_2, f_2, \alpha) - L(P_2, f_2, \alpha) < { \varepsilon \over 2 }, $$
>   which implies 
>   $$ U \left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) - L \left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) < { \varepsilon \over 2 }, \qquad  \mbox{ and  } \qquad  U \left(P, f_2, \alpha \right) - L \left(P, f_2, \alpha \right) < { \varepsilon \over 2 }, \tag{2} $$
>   and this in turn implies that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> &\ U \left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) + U \left(P, f_2, \alpha \right) - \left[ L \left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) + L \left(P, f_2, \alpha \right)  \right] \\ 
> &= \left[  U \left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) - L \left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) \right] + \left[  U \left(P, f_2, \alpha \right) - L \left(P, f_2, \alpha \right)   \right] \\
> &< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
> &= \varepsilon. 
> \end{align} \tag{3} 
> $$
>   But (20) implies that 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> & U ( P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha) \\
> &\leq  \left[ U \left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) + U \left(P, f_2, \alpha \right) \right] - \left[ L \left(P, f_1, \alpha \right) + L \left(P, f_2, \alpha \right) \right]. \tag{4} 
> \end{align}
> $$ 
>   Now (3) and (4) together imply that 
>   $$ U(P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha ) < \varepsilon. \tag{5} $$
>
> Thus for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find a partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ such that (5) holds.  So by Theorem 6.6 in Baby Rudin we can conclude that $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.
>
> Thus 
>   $$ \underline{\int}_a^b f \ d \alpha = \overline{\int}_a^b f \ d \alpha, $$
>   that is, 
>   $$ \sup \left\{ \ L(Q, f, \alpha) \ \colon \ Q \mbox{ is a partition of } [a, b] \ \right\} =  \inf \left\{ \ U(Q, f, \alpha) \ \colon \ Q \mbox{ is a partition of } [a, b] \ \right\}. $$ 
>   Moreover, this common value is denoted by $\int_a^b f \ d \alpha$.
>
> Now from (2) we find that 
>   $$ U\left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) < L \left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) + { \varepsilon \over 2 } \leq \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + { \varepsilon \over 2 },  $$  and 
>   $$  U\left( P, f_2, \alpha \right) < L \left( P, f_2, \alpha \right) + { \varepsilon \over 2 } \leq \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha + { \varepsilon \over 2 },   $$
>   and so 
>   $$  U\left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) < \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + { \varepsilon \over 2 },  \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad  U\left( P, f_2, \alpha \right) < \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha + { \varepsilon \over 2 },  $$
>   and upone adding the last two inequalities we obtain
>   $$ U\left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) + U\left( P, f_2, \alpha \right) < \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha + \varepsilon. \tag{6} $$
>   Now using  (20) we can also conclude 
>   $$ \int_a^b f d \alpha \leq U(P, f, \alpha) \leq  U\left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) + U\left( P, f_2, \alpha \right), $$
>   which implies 
>   $$ \int_a^b f d \alpha \leq  U\left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) + U\left( P, f_2, \alpha \right). \tag{7} $$
>   Therefore  from (6) and (7) we can conclude that for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, we have 
>   $$ \int_a^b f d \alpha < \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha + \varepsilon, $$
>   which implies that 
>   $$ \int_a^b f d \alpha \leq  \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha. \tag{A}$$
>
> Again from (2) we see that 
>   $$ \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha - { \varepsilon \over 2 } \leq U \left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) - { \varepsilon \over 2 } <  
> L \left( P, f_1, \alpha \right), $$
>   and 
>   $$ \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha - { \varepsilon \over 2 } \leq U \left( P, f_2, \alpha \right) - { \varepsilon \over 2 } <  
> L \left( P, f_2, \alpha \right), $$
>   which imply 
>   $$ \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha - { \varepsilon \over 2 } < L \left( P, f_1, \alpha \right), \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad 
> \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha - { \varepsilon \over 2 } < L \left( P, f_2, \alpha \right), $$
>   and upon adding the last two inequalities we obtain 
>   $$ \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha -  \varepsilon < L \left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) + 
> L \left( P, f_2, \alpha \right). \tag{8}$$
>   But from (20) we obtain 
>   $$ L \left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) + 
> L \left( P, f_2, \alpha \right) \leq L(P, f, \alpha) \leq \int_a^b f d \alpha,$$
>   which implies 
>   $$ L \left( P, f_1, \alpha \right) + 
> L \left( P, f_2, \alpha \right) \leq \int_a^b f d \alpha. \tag{9} $$
>   From (8) and (9) we have 
>   $$ \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha -  \varepsilon < \int_a^b f d \alpha, $$
>   and so 
>   $$ \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha  < \int_a^b f d \alpha + \varepsilon  $$
>   for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$. Therefore 
>   $$ \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha  \leq  \int_a^b f d \alpha. \tag{B}  $$
>   Now from (A) and (B) we can conclude that 
>   $$ \int_a^b f d \alpha = \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha, $$
>   as required.

Is my rendering of Rudin's proof correct (and as intended by Rudin)?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Siddhant have you checked it carefully? Do you find my presentation clear enough too?

Comment: yes, the presentation is clear, and the proof is correct. I did a similar proof of this theorem not too long ago.