# Minkowski Inequality for Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Based on Prob. 10, Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition, we have the following result.

> Suppose $p$ is a real number such that $p \geq 1$, and suppose that $f$ and $g$ are complex functions which are  Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to a monotonically increasing function $\alpha$ on an interval $[a, b]$. 
>   Then 
>   $$ \left( \int_a^b \lvert f + g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \leq  \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} +  \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}. \tag{0} $$

Am I right?

Here are the links to my Math SE post on Theorem 6.12 (a) and (b) and Prob. 10 (a), (b), and (c) in Rudin:

[Theorem 6.12 (a) in Baby Rudin: $\int_a^b \left( f_1 + f_2 \right) d \alpha=\int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327046/theorem-6-12-a-in-baby-rudin-int-ab-left-f-1-f-2-right-d-alpha-int)

[Theorem 6.12 (b) in Baby Rudin: If $f_1 \leq f_2$ on $[a, b]$, then $\int_a^b f_1 d\alpha \leq \int_a^b f_2 d\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327229/theorem-6-12-b-in-baby-rudin-if-f-1-leq-f-2-on-a-b-then-int-ab-f)

[Probs. 10 (a), (b), and (c), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Holder's Inequality for Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384521/probs-10-a-b-and-c-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-holders-inequality-for-int)

My Proof:

> First, we suppose that $p=1$. Then since 
>   $$ \lvert f+g \rvert \leq \lvert f \rvert + \lvert g \rvert $$ 
>   on $[a, b]$, therefore  we have 
>   $$ \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert  \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \leq \int_a^b \lvert f  \rvert \ \mathrm{d} \alpha + \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert  \ \mathrm{d} \alpha, $$
>   by Theorem 6.12 (b) in Rudin. This is (0) with $p = 1$.
>
> Now suppose that $p > 1$.
>
> If $ \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha = 0$, then the LHS of (0) equals zero, and since the RHS of (0) is non-negative (by Theorem 6.12 (b) in Rudin), therefore (0) holds.
>
> So we suppose that $ \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \neq  0$.  Then we in fact have 
>   $$ \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha >  0, \tag{1} $$
>   by Theorem 6.12 (b) in Rudin.
>
> Let $q$ be a positive real number such that $1/p + 1/q = 1$. Then 
>   $$ p+q = pq, $$
>   and so 
>   $$ pq - p - q + 1 = 1,$$
>   that is 
>   $$ (p-1)(q-1) = 1;$$
>   therefore 
>   $$ (p-1)q = (p-1)(q-1+1) = (p-1)(q-1) + (p-1) = 1 + (p-1) = p. \tag{2} $$
>
> So, 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha &= \int_a^b \lvert f + g \rvert \, \lvert f+g \rvert^{p-1} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \qquad \mbox{ [ note that $p > 1 $ ] } \\
> &\leq \int_a^b \left( \lvert f \rvert + \lvert g \rvert \right) \lvert f+g \rvert^{p-1} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \qquad \mbox{ [ using Theorem 6.12 (b) in Rudin ] } \\
> &= \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert \, \lvert f+g \rvert^{p-1} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha + 
>  \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert \, \lvert f+g \rvert^{p-1} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using Theorem 6.12 (a) in Rudin ] } \\
> &\leq \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \left( \int_a^b \left\lvert \lvert f+g \rvert^{p-1} \right\rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \\
> & \qquad + \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \left( \int_a^b \left\lvert \lvert f+g \rvert^{p-1} \right\rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \\
> & \qquad \mbox{ [ by Holder's inequality for integrals, or Prob. 10 (c), Chap. 6, in Rudin ] } \\
> &= \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \left( \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^{(p-1)q}  \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \\
> & \qquad +  \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \left( \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^{(p-1)q} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \\
> &= \left[ \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  + \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  \right] \left( \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^{(p-1)q} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \\
> &= \left[ \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  + \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  \right] \left( \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^{p} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q}. \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using (2) above ] }
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Thus we have shown that 
>   $$ \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \leq \left[ \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  + \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  \right] \left( \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^{p} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q}. \tag{3} $$
>   And as 
>   $$ \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha > 0, $$ 
>   by (1) above, so 
>   $$ \left( \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^{p} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} > 0 $$
>   as well; dividing (3) out by this integral we obtain 
>   $$ \frac{\int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha }{\left( \int_a^b \lvert f+g \rvert^{p} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} } \leq  \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  + \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}.  $$
>   which is the same as (0) above, because $1 - 1/q = 1/p$.

Is my proof correct? If so, then is it as rigorous as Rudin demands? If not, then where are the issues?

Is my presentation clear enough for a not-so-sharp student who is taking their very first course in analysis?

Comment: I have read it three times now. I haven't checked the proofs of the facts you have used [I know them and I know they're valid]. Kudos to you for a very detailed proof. It's very undergraduate friendly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly: **yes**, your answer is logically correct and it is very clear.

---

If you want the proof to be slightly less lengthy, the simple algebra in (2) could have been written in just one line: the equality $1/p+1/q=1$ implies that
$$
(p-1)q=(p-1)\cdot\frac{1}{1-1/p}=p.
$$

Also, if you want to save your labor to type/write the integral sign, use the norm notation $\|\cdot\|_p$.