# Prob. 11, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Triangle Inequality for Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals using $L^2$-Norm

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, integral-inequality

Here is Prob. 11, Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Let $\alpha$ be a fixed increasing function on $[a, b]$. For $u \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$, define
> $$ \lVert u \rVert_2 = \left\{ \int_a^b \lvert u \rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right\}^{1/2}. $$
> Suppose $f, g, h \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$, and prove the triangle inequality
> $$ \lVert f-h \rVert_2 \leq  \lVert f-g \rVert_2 + \lVert g-h \rVert_2 $$
> as a consequence of the Schwarz inequality, . . .

My Attempt:

Here is the link to my Math SE post on the  Minkowski's inequality for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals:

[Minkowski Inequality for Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385205/minkowski-inequality-for-riemann-stieltjes-integrals)

> Supposing that $f, g, h$ are complex functions in $\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$, we obtain
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & \lVert f-h \rVert_2  \\
> &= \left(  \int_a^b \lvert f-h \rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/2} \\
> &= \left(  \int_a^b \left\lvert \, (f-g)\, + \,  (g-h) \, \right\rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/2} \\
> &\leq  \left(  \int_a^b \left\lvert f-g  \right\rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/2}  + \left(  \int_a^b \left\lvert g-h  \right\rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/2} \qquad \mbox{ [ using Minkowski's inequality ] } \\ 
> &= \lVert f-g \rVert_2 + \lVert g-h \rVert_2, 
> \end{align}
> $$
> as required.

Is my proof correct and the same as demanded by Rudin?

P.S.:

> On $[a, b]$, as
> $$0 \leq \left\lvert f - h \right\rvert = \left\lvert (f-g) + (g-h) \right\rvert \leq \left\lvert f-g \right\rvert +  \left\lvert g-h \right\rvert, $$
> so
> \begin{align}
> & \ \ \  \left\lvert f - h \right\rvert^2 \\ 
> &\leq  \left( \left\lvert f-g \right\rvert + \left\lvert g-h \right\rvert \right)^2 \\ 
> &= \left\lvert f-g \right\rvert^2 + 2 \left\lvert f-g \right\rvert \left\lvert g-h \right\rvert +  \left\lvert g-h \right\rvert^2. 
> \end{align}
> Therefore we have
> \begin{align}
> & \ \ \ \int_a^b \left\lvert f - h \right\rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \\ 
> &\leq \int_a^b \left( \left\lvert f-g \right\rvert^2 + 2 \left\lvert f-g \right\rvert \left\lvert g-h \right\rvert +  \left\lvert g-h \right\rvert^2 \right) \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ by Theorem 6.12 (b) in Rudin ] } \\
> &= \int_a^b  \left\lvert f-g \right\rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha + 2 \int_a^b  \left\lvert f-g \right\rvert \left\lvert g-h \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} \alpha + \int_a^b \left\lvert g-h \right\rvert^2  \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \\ 
> &\qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ by Theorem 6.12 (a) in Rudin ] } \\
> &\leq \int_a^b  \left\lvert f-g \right\rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha + 2 \left( \int_a^b \lvert f-g \rvert^{2} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_a^b \lvert g - h \rvert^{2} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/2} \\
> & \qquad + \int_a^b \left\lvert g-h \right\rvert^2  \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \\ 
> &  \qquad \mbox{ [ by Holder's inequality for integrals with $p=2$ ] } \\
> &= \left[ \left( \int_a^b \lvert f-g \rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/2}  + \left( \int_a^b \lvert g - h \rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/2}  \right]^2.  
> \end{align}
> Thus we have obtained the inequality
> \begin{align} 
> & \ \ \  \int_a^b \left\lvert f - h \right\rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \\ 
> &\leq \left[ \left( \int_a^b \lvert f-g \rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{\frac12}  + \left( \int_a^b \lvert g - h \rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{\frac12}  \right]^2. \tag{1} 
> \end{align}

> Since all the integrals in (1) are non-negative (and so are their square roots), therefore upon taking the square roots on both sieds of (1), we obtain
> \begin{align}
> & \ \ \  \left( \int_a^b \left\lvert f - h \right\rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{\frac12} \\ 
> & \leq \left( \int_a^b \lvert f-g \rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{\frac12}  + \left( \int_a^b \lvert g - h \rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{\frac12} , 
> \end{align}
> which is the same as
> $$ \lVert f-h \rVert_2 \leq \lVert f- g \rVert_2 + \lVert g-h \rVert_2, $$
> as required.

Here are the links to some relevant Math SE posts of mine:

[Theorem 6.12 (a) in Baby Rudin: $\int_a^b \left( f_1 + f_2 \right) d \alpha=\int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327046/theorem-6-12-a-in-baby-rudin-int-ab-left-f-1-f-2-right-d-alpha-int)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327134/theorem-6-12-a-in-baby-rudin-if-f-in-mathscrr-alpha-on-a-b-then-c

[Theorem 6.12 (b) in Baby Rudin: If $f_1 \leq f_2$ on $[a, b]$, then $\int_a^b f_1 d\alpha \leq \int_a^b f_2 d\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327229/theorem-6-12-b-in-baby-rudin-if-f-1-leq-f-2-on-a-b-then-int-ab-f)

[Probs. 10 (a), (b), and (c), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Holder's Inequality for Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384521/probs-10-a-b-and-c-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-holders-inequality-for-int)

Comment: In your first approach, it should be $(\int_a^b |f-h|^2 \ d \alpha)^{ \frac {1}{2} }$ instead of $(\int_a^b |f-h| \ d \alpha)^{ \frac {1}{2} }$

Answer (score 0):

Minkowski's inequality *is* the triangle inequality in this case, so you are using what you are asked to prove in your proof.

Since all the norms are nonnegative, it suffices to prove
$$\|f-h\|_2^2 \le (\|f-g\|_2 + \|g-h\|_2)^2.$$
By writing $f-h=f-g+g-h$ and expanding both sides, we reduce the inequality to
$$2\langle f-g,g-h\rangle \le 2 \|f-g\|_2 \|g-h\|_2,$$
where
$$\langle f-g, g-h\rangle := \int_a^b (f-g)(g-h) \mathop{d\alpha}.$$
The above inequality is simply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: please have a look at my post now. I've added a P.S.

Answer (score 0):

As @angryavian pointed out, your first attempt missed Rudin's point. The original problem is as follows:

> [image]

You have replaced "as in the proof of Theorem 1.37" with three dots in your post and thus made things complicated.

---

To answer your edited question: Your second attempt in the "P.S." part is **correct**. "Hölder inequality" in your argument is the same as the "Schwarz inequality", which is explicitly mentioned in the second last phrase of the problem: "as a consequence of the Schwarz inequality".