# Prob. 12, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Denseness of $\mathrm{C}[a,b]$ in $L^2[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, lp-spaces

Here is Prob. 12, Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> With the notations of Exercise 11, suppose $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Prove that there exists a continuous function $g$ on $[a, b]$ such that $\lVert f-g \rVert_2 < \varepsilon$.

> *Hint:* Let $P = \left\{ \ x_0, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ be a suitable partition of $[a, b]$, define
> $$ g(t) = \frac{ x_i - t }{ \Delta x_i } f \left( x_{i-1} \right) + \frac{ t- x_{i-1} }{ \Delta x_i } f \left( x_i \right) $$
> if $x_{i-1} \leq t \leq x_i$.

My Attempt:

Here is the link to one of my Math SE posts in which I have included Definitions 6.1 and 6.2 from Rudin, where all the notation to be used below is  given:

[Theorem 6.15 in Baby Rudin: If $a<s<b$, $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, $f$ is continuous at $s$, and $\alpha(x)=I(x-s)$, then . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329858/theorem-6-15-in-baby-rudin-if-asb-f-is-bounded-on-a-b-f-is-contin)

> Let us first assume that $f$ is a real function defined on $[a, b]$. As $f$ is  Riemann-Stieltjes integrable on $[a, b]$, so it is  bounded on $[a, b]$. Let us put
> $$ M \colon= \sup \left\{ \ \lvert f(x) \rvert \ \colon \ a \leq x \leq b \ \right\}. \tag{A} $$

> Again as $f$ is  Riemann-Stieltjes integrable on $[a, b]$, so by Theorem 6.4 in Rudin we can find a partition $P = \left\{ \ x_0, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ of $[a, b]$ for which
> $$ U(P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha) < \frac{\varepsilon^2 }{4 M \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] + 1  }. \tag{B}$$
> Then for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we have
> $$ \left( M_i - m_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i  < \frac{\varepsilon^2 }{4 M \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] + 1  }. \tag{C}$$

> For each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, and for every $t_i$ such that  $x_{i-1} \leq t_i \leq x_i$, we see that
> $$
> \begin{align}
>  \left\lvert f\left(t_i \right) - g \left(t_i \right) \right\rvert &= \left\lvert \frac{x_i - t_i + t_i - x_{i-1} }{\Delta x_i } f\left(t_i \right) - \left[ \frac{ x_i - t_i }{ \Delta x_i } f \left( x_{i-1} \right) + \frac{ t_i- x_{i-1} }{ \Delta x_i } f \left( x_i \right)  \right] \right\rvert  \\
> &= \left\lvert \frac{x_i - t_i }{\Delta x_i} \left[ f \left(t_i \right) - f \left( x_{i-1} \right) \right] + \frac{ t_i - x_{i-1} }{\Delta x_i} \left[ f \left(t_i \right) - f \left( x_i  \right) \right] \right\rvert \\
> &\leq \frac{x_i - t_i }{\Delta x_i} \left\lvert f \left(t_i \right) - f \left( x_{i-1} \right)  \right\rvert + \frac{ t_i - x_{i-1} }{\Delta x_i} \left\lvert f \left(t_i \right) - f \left( x_i  \right)  \right\rvert \\
> &\leq \frac{x_i - t_i }{\Delta x_i} \left( M_i - m_i \right)  + \frac{t_i - x_{i-1} }{\Delta x_i} \left( M_i - m_i \right) \\
> &  \mbox{ [ where $m_i \colon= \inf \left\{ \ f(t) \ \colon \ x_{i-1} \leq t \leq x_i \ \right\}$, and $M_i \colon= \sup \left\{ \ f(t) \ \colon \ x_{i-1} \leq t \leq x_i \ \right\}$ ] } \\
> &= M_i - m_i, 
> \end{align}
> $$
> which implies that
> $$ \left\lvert f\left(t_i \right) - g \left(t_i \right) \right\rvert^2 \leq \left( M_i - m_i \right)^2, $$
> and so
> $$ \left\lvert f \left(t_i \right) - g \left(t_i \right) \right\rvert^2 \Delta \alpha_i \leq \left( M_i - m_i \right)^2 \Delta \alpha_i. $$
> Therefore, for each $t_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right]$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we have
> $$
> \begin{align}
> 0 &\leq  \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lvert f \left(t_i \right) - g \left(t_i \right) \right\rvert^2 \Delta \alpha_i  \\
> &\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left( M_i - m_i \right)^2 \Delta \alpha_i \\
> &\leq \sum_{i-1}^n 2M \left( M_i - m_i \right) \Delta \alpha_i \qquad \mbox{ [ using (A) above ] } \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^n 2 M \frac{ \varepsilon^2 }{ 4 M \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] + 1} \Delta \alpha_i \qquad \mbox{ [ using (C) above ] } \\
> &= 2M \frac{ \varepsilon^2 }{ 4M \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] + 1} \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right]\\
> &< \frac{\varepsilon^2 }{2}, 
> \end{align}
> $$
> and so
> $$ - \frac{\varepsilon^2 }{2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lvert f \left(t_i \right) - g \left(t_i \right) \right\rvert^2 \Delta \alpha_i \leq  \frac{\varepsilon^2 }{2}. \tag{0}  $$

> But
> $$ L \left(P, \lvert f-g \rvert^2 , \alpha \right) = \inf \left\{ \ \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lvert f \left(t_i \right) - g \left(t_i \right) \right\rvert^2 \Delta \alpha_i  \ \colon \ t_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right] \ i = 1, \ldots, n \ \right\}, \tag{1} $$
> and
> $$ U \left( P, \lvert f-g \rvert^2 , \alpha \right) = \sup \left\{ \ \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lvert f \left(t_i \right) - g \left(t_i \right) \right\rvert^2 \Delta \alpha_i  \ \colon \ t_i \in \left[ x_{i-1}, x_i \right] \ i = 1, \ldots, n \ \right\}. \tag{2} $$

Here is the link to a relevant post of mine here on Math SE:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358808/riemann-stieltjes-upper-and-lower-sums-as-suprema-and-infima

> Now from (0), (1), and (2)  we can conclude that
> $$ - \frac{\varepsilon^2 }{2} \leq L \left( P, \lvert f-g \rvert^2, \alpha \right) \leq U \left( P , \lvert f-g \rvert^2 , \alpha \right) \leq \frac{\varepsilon^2 }{2}. \tag{3}   $$

> As $g$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, so $g \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$, by Theorem 6.8 in Rudin.

> Now as $f, g \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$, so $f - g \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$, by Theorem 6.12 (a) in Rudin.

Here are the links to my Math SE post on Theorem 6.12 (a) in Rudin:

[Theorem 6.12 (a) in Baby Rudin: $\int_a^b \left( f_1 + f_2 \right) d \alpha=\int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327046/theorem-6-12-a-in-baby-rudin-int-ab-left-f-1-f-2-right-d-alpha-int)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327134/theorem-6-12-a-in-baby-rudin-if-f-in-mathscrr-alpha-on-a-b-then-c

> Furthermore, as $ f-g  \in \mathscr{R} (\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$, so $ \lvert f-g  \rvert \in \mathscr{R} (\alpha) $ on $[a, b]$ as well, by virtue of Theorem 6.13 (b) in Rudin.

> Finally, as $ \lvert f-g  \rvert  \in \mathscr{R} (\alpha) $ on $[a, b]$ and as the map $y \mapsto y^2$ is continuous on all of  $[0, +\infty)$, so we can conclude that
> $ \lvert f-g  \rvert^2  \in \mathscr{R} (\alpha) $ on $[a, b]$  also, by virtue of Theorem 6.11 in Rudin.

> Thus $\int_a^b \lvert f-g \rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha $ exists.  Moreover, for any partition $Q$ of $[a, b]$, we have the inequalities
> $$ L \left( Q, \lvert f-g \rvert^2, \alpha \right) \leq \int_a^b \lvert f-g \rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \leq  U \left( Q, \lvert f-g \rvert^2 , \alpha \right). \tag{4} $$

> From (3) and (4) we can conclude that
> $$ - \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \leq \int_a^b \lvert f-g \rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \leq \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2}. \tag{5} $$

> But as $\lvert f - g \rvert^2 \geq 0$ on $[a, b]$, so by Theorem 6.12 (b) in Rudin
> $$ \int_a^b \lvert f - g \rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \geq 0. \tag{6} $$

Here is the link to my Math SE post on Theorem 6.12 (b) in Rudin:

[Theorem 6.12 (b) in Baby Rudin: If $f_1 \leq f_2$ on $[a, b]$, then $\int_a^b f_1 d\alpha \leq \int_a^b f_2 d\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327229/theorem-6-12-b-in-baby-rudin-if-f-1-leq-f-2-on-a-b-then-int-ab-f)

> From (5) and (6) we obtain
> $$ 0 \leq \int_a^b \lvert f - g \rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \leq \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} < \varepsilon^2. $$
> Therefore,
> $$ \left( \int_a^b \lvert f - g \rvert^2 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/2} < \varepsilon, $$
> which is the same as
> $$ \lVert f-g \rVert_2 < \varepsilon. $$
> And the function $g$ is continuous on $[a, b]$.

Is my proof correct? Is it rigorous enough? If not, then where does it lack?

How to rigorously show that this  function $g$ is continuous?

> Now we assume that $f$ is a complex function defined on $[a, b]$. Then $f = \Re f + \iota \Im f$, where $\Re f$ and $\Im f$ are real functions defined on $[a, b]$.

> As $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$ on $[a, b]$, so are $\Re f$ and $\Im f$. Then we have
> $$ \int_a^b f \ \mathrm{d} \alpha =  \int_a^b \Re f \ \mathrm{d} \alpha +  \iota \int_a^b \Im f \ \mathrm{d} \alpha.  $$

> Applying the result just proved for real functions to $\Re f$ and $\Im f$, we can conclude that there are continuous functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ on $[a, b]$ such that
> $$ \left\lVert \Re f \ - \ g_1 \right\rVert < \frac{ \varepsilon}{4}, $$
> and
> $$ \left\lVert \Im f \ - \ g_2  \right\rVert < \frac{ \varepsilon}{4}; $$
> therefore if we put $ g \colon= g_1 + \iota g_2$ on $[a, b]$, we  have
> $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \lVert f - g \rVert_2 &= \left\lVert \left( \Re f + \iota \Im f \right) \ - 
> \ \left( g_1 + \iota g_2 \right) \right\rVert_2 \\
> &= \left\lVert \left( \Re f - g_1 \right) \ + \ \iota  
>  \left( \Im f -  g_2 \right) \right\rVert_2 \\
> &\leq \left\lVert  \Re f - g_1 \right\rVert_2 \ + \ \left\lVert \iota  
>  \left( \Im f -  g_2 \right) \right\rVert_2 \\
> &= \left\lVert  \Re f - g_1 \right\rVert_2 \ + \ \lvert \iota \rvert \cdot 
> \left\lVert \Im f -  g_2  \right\rVert_2 \\ 
> &= \left\lVert  \Re f - g_1 \right\rVert_2 \ + \ 
> \left\lVert \Im f -  g_2  \right\rVert_2 \\
> &< \frac{\varepsilon}{4} + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} \\
> &< \varepsilon.
> \end{align}
> $$

> Finally, as $g_1 = \Re g$ and $g_2 = \Im g$ are both continuous on
> $[a, b]$, so is $g$.

Is this proof for complex functions correct too? If so,
is it rigorous enough too? If not, then what is it that I am missing
out on?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima why? Is it because you're being put off by the length of my post?

Comment: It seems that your proof is right. In (0), lower bound should be 0 if $\alpha$ is increasing.

Comment: I answered the question but realized I made a mistake, so I deleted the answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @kimchilover there is no error in my proof. The post justifying the identity you consider to be an error has been deleted by the community and so might not be accessible to you.

Comment: I'm sorry; I made a mistake.